# VSFTPD on embedded system: limit user acess to specific folder only

Tags: linux, embedded, vsftpd

In my application I have a folder `/LD` and one user `test_user`. I want this user to have access to only this `/LD` folder.

But when I connect through Filezilla FTP client then by default `/LD` is loaded but the user can navigate to other folders also.

I am using a Linux 4.9 embedded system. I have the `chroot`, `adduser`, `addgroup` and `chmod` commands. I don't have the `usermod` command.

Is what I want possible?

Answer (score 1):

First, you'll have to make `/LD` be the home directory of `test_user`. You said you don't have the `usermod` command; then use `vipw` instead, or if that is not available either, just ensure the user is not currently logged in and edit `/etc/passwd` directly.

Then, check the [vsftpd.conf man page](http://vsftpd.beasts.org/vsftpd_conf.html) and read the descriptions of options `chroot_local_user`, `chroot_list_enable` and `chroot_list_file`.

If you wish all (or most) users' FTP connections to be restricted to their home directories, you can set `chroot_local_user` to YES and use the `/etc/vsftpd.chroot_list` file (or whatever file is specified by the `chroot_list_file` option) to specify exceptions.

If only `test_user` must be restricted, then leave `chroot_local_user` to NO, and instead set `chroot_list_enable` to YES, and then add `test_user` to `/etc/vsftpd.chroot_list` file (or whatever file is specified by the `chroot_list_file` option). You can create the file if it does not already exist.

As a result of these actions, when `test_user` logs in on an FTP connection, they will see the `/LD` directory as the root directory (`/`). As a result, it will be impossible for them to navigate outside the `/LD` directory tree, as for their FTP connection the rest of the filesystem just won't exist. The user may still be able to access any sub-directories of `/LD`; if this is not desirable, use filesystem permissions to block that.

---

First identify the user(s) and/or group(s) that need to access the sub-directories of /LD. Ideally, all the users of sub-directories of /LD shoud belong to a single group (let's call it `LDsub`) and `test_user` should not be part of that group. The `test_user` should be alone in another group (let's call it `LDftp` for example). The members of the `LDsub` group may or may not be members of the `LDftp` group too, depending on whether or not they need write access to the `/LD` directory itself.

If you don't have the `usermod` or `groupmod` commands, you can edit the group memberships via `vigr` or just by editing `/etc/group`.

Now, you can use the `chown` command to set the ownership of the `/LD` directory and `chmod` to set the permissions:

```
chown root:LDftp /LD
chmod 775 /LD        #this will be drwxrwxr-x
```

Now `test_user` will have write access to the `/LD` directory via the group membership, but they won't be the owner of the directory so they cannot change its permissions. The "everyone r-x" permissions will allow the members of the `LDsub` group to pass through this directory to access its sub-directories as allowed by their permissions.

The subdirectories of /LD can be owned by anyone as required, as long as it isn't the `test_user`. The group of those sub-directories should be set to `LDsub`and permissions as follows:

```
chgrp LDsub /LD/subdirectory  # or chown <not_test_user>:LDsub /LD/subdirectory
chmod 770 /LD/subdirectory   # this will be drwxrwx---
```

Be aware that if `test_user` has write access to `/LD`, it necessarily means that they can rename any sub-directories, create new ones and delete any **empty** sub-directories.

If your requirements are more complex than this, it may be easier to make sure the ACL support is enabled in the filesystem and use ACLs to specify the user(s) and/or group(s) allowed to access to the sub-directories of /LD. See the man pages of the `getfacl` and `setfacl` commands, and/or [this webpage](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/usetfacl.htm) for details.

---

Alternatively, you could consider moving the sub-directories of `/LD` to another location and using symbolic links to make the directory paths work as before.

```
mv /LD/subdirectory /elsewhere/subdirectory
ln -s /elsewhere/subdirectory /LD/subdirectory
```

For any user other than `test_user` in a FTP session, these symbolic links will be usable as usual. But since `test_user`'s FTP session will be chrooted to `/LD`, for them these symbolic links will appear as unusable broken links. If `test_user` has write access to `/LD`, they can delete the "broken" links though.

Comment: can you share steps to do so?

Comment: Edited my answer; if you need more clarification, please specify which part you're having problems with.